# Modifying a CoBlocks Filter in Functions

Tags: filters

I'm trying to modify `slidestoshow` parameter in CoBlocks Carousel block via my theme's functions. Everything in the Codex implies modifying/passing the variable but looking at the code, it appears it's an [anonymous function?] Forgive me if this term is incorrect.

I've tried both `apply_filters()` and `add_filters()` to replace the entire array rather than the individual key/value. I've tried removing the existing filter and adding it again but I'm not sure if the way it's coded is preventing me from making my modification.

Do I need to call the plugin Class `CoBlocks_Settings`?

Here is the original plugin code:

```
$block_content = sprintf(
'<div class="%1$s"><div class="coblocks-slick pb-8" data-slick="%2$s">',
    esc_attr( $class ),
    esc_attr(
        wp_json_encode(
            /**
             * Filter the slick slider carousel settings
             *
             * @var array Slick slider settings.
            */
            (array) apply_filters(
                'coblocks_post_carousel_settings',
                    array(
                    'slidesToScroll' => 1,
                    'arrow'          => true,
                    'slidesToShow'   => $attributes['columns'],
                    'infinite'       => true,
                    'adaptiveHeight' => false,
                    'draggable'      => true,
                    'responsive'     => array(
                        array(
                            'breakpoint' => 1024,
                            'settings'   => array(
                                'slidesToShow' => 3,
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'breakpoint' => 600,
                            'settings'   => array(
                                'slidesToShow' => 2,
                            ),
                        ),
                        array(
                            'breakpoint' => 480,
                            'settings'   => array(
                                'slidesToShow' => 1,
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

First, I tried just overriding it with:

```
apply_filters( 'coblocks_post_carousel_settings',  array( ... ));
```

Second, here's where I'm at in Functions:

```
apply_filters( 'coblocks_post_carousel_settings', 'my_filter_coblocks_carousel' );
function my_filter_coblocks_carousel() {
    $carousel = array(
        'slidesToScroll' => 1,
        'arrow'          => true,
        'slidesToShow'   => $attributes['columns'],
        'infinite'       => true,
        'adaptiveHeight' => false,
        'draggable'      => true,
        'responsive'     => array(
            array(
                'breakpoint' => 1024,
                'settings'   => array(
                    'slidesToShow' => 4,
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'breakpoint' => 600,
                'settings'   => array(
                    'slidesToShow' => 4,
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'breakpoint' => 480,
                'settings'   => array(
                    'slidesToShow' => 4,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $carousel;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) calls all callbacks added via [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for the specific filter hook, which is `coblocks_post_carousel_settings` in your case, so instead of:

```php
apply_filters( 'coblocks_post_carousel_settings', 'my_filter_coblocks_carousel' );
```

*You* should actually do:

```php
// You should use add_filter() and not apply_filters().
add_filter( 'coblocks_post_carousel_settings', 'my_filter_coblocks_carousel' );
```

And, your callback should accept the slider settings passed by the plugin to `apply_filters()` — which then passes the settings (which is an array) to your callback. So define your callback like so and then just change the settings (or array items) that you wish to change:

```php
function my_filter_coblocks_carousel( $settings ) {
    $settings['slidesToShow'] = 5;
    return $settings;
}
```

Please check the function reference (see links above) for more details, but basically, if you want others to filter something in your code, you use `apply_filters()` to let that something to be filtered by plugin or some custom code. And in your case, the (CoBlocks) plugin calls `apply_filters()` and you're part of that "others", thus you use `add_filter()` and not `apply_filters()`. I hope that makes sense? :)

### Update: Examples for modifying the inner `slidesToShow` settings

So this is actually generic PHP stuff and it depends on you on how would you modify that inner `slidesToShow` in the `responsive` array items, but hopefully these help you:

```php
// So this would all be in the my_filter_coblocks_carousel() function:

// Change the slidesToShow setting **only** for the "600" breakpoint.
foreach ( $settings['responsive'] as $i => $arr ) {
    if ( 600 === $arr['breakpoint'] ) {
        $settings['responsive'][ $i ]['settings']['slidesToShow'] = 3;
    }
}

// Add a new breakpoint.
$settings['responsive'][] = array(
    'breakpoint' => 320,
    'settings'   => array(
        'slidesToShow' => 1,
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. You mention passing the sidebar settings, but ```slidesToShow``` is not a sidebar option & not part of the original ```$args``` array at the top of the coBlocks file. Since it's just hardcoded and json-encoded directly within the ```apply_filter``` tag, this array is not really passed to the original $args/settings array, correct? -- Do I need to have the full assoc. array, like ```$settings[][]['slidesToShow']```  since there are 3 breakpoints? Does ```$settings``` need to be renamed as an existing CoBlocks variable?

Comment: Sorry, that "sidebar" was a typo and I meant to say, "slider". And in my answer, the point is that the plugin passes one parameter to the filter (`coblocks_post_carousel_settings`) callbacks and that parameter is an array with `slidesToShow` being one of the items, so you just need to change the value to whatever you want. And please, check the docs to further understand how `apply_filters()` and `add_filter()` work.

Comment: I hope the examples in my revised answer helps, and if my answer answered your question, please consider marking it as "correct" - just tick the check-mark next to my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and detailed replies. Sometimes it takes a little explanation to learn things. Much appreciated.